# How to animate div using jQuery Flip

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is working fine when the user triggers a mouse over event, however I want to set a timer to animate without any trigger - like auto animating. How can I do that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".flip").flip({
    axis: 'y',
    trigger: 'hover'
  });
});
```

```html
<div class=" flip  col-md-3">
  <div class="flip">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="title">Front Wise</div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="title">Back Wise</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the library: https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/

Comment: Could you please link to the `flip()` library you're using.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan here you go https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/

Comment: Thanks. @gurvinder372 has your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the **trigger** value to `manual`, check the [doc](https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/#Options)

```
$(".flip").flip({
    axis: 'y',
    trigger: 'manual'
});

setTimeout( function() {
  $(".flip").flip('toggle');
}, 100); //this will trigger the flip after 100 millisecond
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".flip").flip({
    axis: 'y',
    trigger: 'manual'
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".flip").flip('toggle');
  }, 5000); //this will trigger the flip after 100 millisecond

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/master/dist/jquery.flip.js"></script>
Flip below will be triggered in 5 seconds
<div class=" flip  col-md-3">
  <div class="flip">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="title">Front Wise</div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="title">Back Wise</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```